# Android Studio: Could not find jp.co.cyberagent.android:gpuimage:2.0.4

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I'm using Android Studio 2020.3.1 Patch 4.
I built gradle and it was successful, but when I try running my app, I get error

```
could not find jp.co.cyberagent.android:gpuimage:2.0.4.

Required by:
     project:app
```

I added gradle dependency

```
implementation 'jp.co.cyberagent.android:gpuimage:2.0.4'
```

I also added in the build.gradle

```
sourceset{
main.jniLibs.srcDirs =["libs"]
}
```

as suggested from

["GPUImage.h" not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12105698/gpuimage-h-not-found)

and

[How to include *.so library in Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24357687/how-to-include-so-library-in-android-studio)

But nothing is working. still gives me the same error message

Answer (score 1):

After Long Search

I that's the problem is that I removed

```
jcenter()
```

from gradle repository. I removed it because it is deprecated but it turns out that `jcenter()` is the only repository containing gpuimage as of current.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `mavenCentral` instead of `jcenter` for this `jp.co.cyberagent.android:gpuimage:2.x.x`.

cf. [official doc](https://github.com/cats-oss/android-gpuimage)

Answer (score 0):

Add this line in Module build.gradle

> implementation
> 'jp.co.cyberagent.android.gpuimage:gpuimage-library:1.4.1'

and add this line in project level build.gradle

> mavenCentral()

then click on sync now issue solve